# Why does seek return None in python?

Tags: python, seek

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) clearly says:

> Return the new absolute position.

However, `seek` appears to return `None` (same behavior also on Linux):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> >>> >>> >>> import os
>>> f=open("......","r")
>>> f.readline()
'......\n'
>>> f.tell()
44
>>> f.seek(0,2)
>>> f.tell()
9636
```

1. Is this a know bug?
2. Is this a doc or implementation bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are reading the *wrong documentation*. You need to look at [`file.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) when using Python 2:

> There is no return value.

Using [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) is fine, and if you do, you'll get a *different* object, whose `seek()` method *does* return the current position:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 17:17:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import io
>>> f = io.open('data.json')
>>> f.seek(0, 2)
39L
>>> type(f)
<type '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> f = open('data.json')
>>> f.seek(0, 2)
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
```

The [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) is the new I/O architecture for Python 3, available in Python 2 as well. The Python 3 [built-in `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is an alias for `io.open()`, but not yet so in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Martjin's answer, use `type()` to inspect the variable's type:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("foo", "r")
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
```

By inspecting the object type, you will see that the variable `f` is not a member of `io`, but of `file`, and so the documentation to look up would be different.

Comment: It should be a comment since it is not an answer to the original question and you just bring additional information... If the answer of Martjin disappears (due to a cataclysm for example), your answer would not be enough to answer the question.